# How to get multiple value in single prompt JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, prompt

How to get multiple values in single prompt JavaScript. Doesn't use the input form

```
var toText = prompt("From", "Lorem");
var fromText = prompt("To", "Ipsum");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get multiple values by separating them with commas and using `split` method like this:

```js
// Input: Hello, World, Lorem

const promptInput = prompt("Enter comma separated values");
const values = promptInput.split(",")
console.log(values)

// Output: ["Hello", "World", "Lorem"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get only one input using prompt. You will either have to display multiple prompts or implement a custom dialog window which will basically be a form.

Answer (score 0):

window. prompt() instructs the browser to display a dialog with an optional message prompting the user to **input** some text, and to wait until the user either submits the text or cancels the dialog.- this is from mdn, you need input